# rewrite then redirecting to same page with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Default URL: `domain.com/contact.php`

Rewrite URL to: `domain.com/contactus`

Then when I have to enter the default URL to: `domain.com/contact.php` it should redirect (open) to `domain.com/contactus`

**I have tried**

```
RewriteRule ^contactus$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule contact.php contactus [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one redirect rule to force new URI in browsers and one rewrite to forward new URI to php file:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/contact\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /contactus? [L,R=301] 

# rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^contactus/?$ contact.php [L,NC]
```

`?` in target URI will remove existing query string.

Comment: Great, can you explain about `\s`

Comment: It matches a whitespaces before URI to make sure we don't match something like `/subdir/contact.php`

Comment: Thank you so much, another question, when if default URL format is: `domain.com/contact.php?action=billing` ? I have tried `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/contact\.php\?action=billing[?\s] [NC]` but not work.

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /contact\.php\?action=billing [NC]`

Comment: this redirect as `domain.com/contactus?action=billing`

Comment: check updated answer. You need to add `?` at the end of target to remove previous query string.